# Create a 2d html5 click and play game with scala and play2 framework or playN?

Tags: html, scala, playframework, playn

I'm making a technological watch in order to create a simple little click and play game in html5 / canvas, probably like this : Geminie Rue ( http://wadjeteyegames.com/gemini-rue.html ) or machinarium ( http://machinarium.net/demo/ )

I want to write this game in scala using great html5 power feature and portability : canvas, websocket, etc.

It seems there is two way to make this, using the google playN framework ( http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/kick-ass-game-programming-with-google-web-toolkit.html and http://code.google.com/p/playn/) with scala-gwt, or try to use the play 2 framework with html5 features.

Do you have some advice,experience or example for game creation with these technology ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

PlayN by design supports game development. GWT is cool too, but if your game is meant to be a simple one, IMO PlayN may save you a lot of work.

Good luck!